# How to fix to Local Disk G Missing Issue?

Tags: hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery

I recently set up Windows 10 but after a few days my external hard drive Drive "G" is showing a local disk and can not access it. What is the reason and how can i recover this drive and access again all of my data stored in drive G

Comment: What shows when you click on it

Comment: Whenever I click on it the message shows up can not access and master boot table error

Comment: Seems like perhaps the external drive is broken.

Comment: How does it look in diskmgmt.msc, or in third-party tool DiskGenius? Add screenshot to question.